# Need download voice message from Telegram on Python

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I started developing a pet project related to telegram bot. One of the points was the question, **how to download a voice message from the bot?**

Task: Need to download a audiofile from telegram bot and save in project folder.

**GetUpdates**
https://api.telegram.org/bot/getUpdates:

```
{"duration":2,"mime_type":"audio/ogg","file_id":"<file_id>","file_unique_id":"<file_unique_id>","file_size":8858}}}]}
```

I checked **[pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) documentation**, but I didn't find an explanation for exactly how to download the file.

I created the code based on the documentation:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice'])
def voice_processing(message):
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.voice.file_id)
    file = requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{0}/{1}'.format(cfg.TOKEN, file_info.file_path))
```

```
print(type(file), file)
------------------------------------------------------------
Output: <class 'requests.models.Response'>, <Response [200]>
```

I also found one **example** where the author downloaded audio in **chunks**. How exactly I did not understand, but it used a **similar function**:

```
def read_chunks(chunk_size, bytes):
    while True:
        chunk = bytes[:chunk_size]
        bytes = bytes[chunk_size:]

        yield chunk

        if not bytes:
            break
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the github of the project there is an [example](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/download_file_example.py) for that:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice'])
def voice_processing(message):
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.voice.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    with open('new_file.ogg', 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/v13.11/), you can download a voice note like this:

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CallbackContext, MessageHandler, Filters


def get_voice(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    # get basic info about the voice note file and prepare it for downloading
    new_file = context.bot.get_file(update.message.voice.file_id)
    # download the voice note as a file
    new_file.download(f"voice_note.ogg")

updater = Updater("1234:TOKEN")

# Add handler for voice messages
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.voice , get_voice))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```